# Switching between data bases in Java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, database-connection

I want to obtain some data in my java code from a netezza DB, hold that in memory and then switch to an oracle db and run some analysis. However, when I try and switch to the second db below, I get the  following error:

```
org.netezza.util.PSQLEexception: Invalid URL format
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought switching the `Class.forName` would be enough.
Note that - I can set up the oracle connection separately (when I don't do netezza). But the problem arises when I try to switch from netezza to Oracle

```
Class.forName("org.netezza.Driver");

System.out.println(" Connecting ... ");

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);

System.out.println("Connected "+ conn);

PreparedStatement pstat = conn.prepareStatement("some query");

ResultSet rstru = pstat.executeQuery();

while(rstru.next()){
    //Do some thing
}
rstru.close();

if(conn != null) conn.close();

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
System.out.println("Connecting to Oracle");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("some other url", "user2", "passwrd2"); 
System.out.println("Connected "+ conn);

pstat = conn.prepareStatement("second query");

rstru=pstat.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Well...your URL format is incorrect. All `Class.forName()` does with JDBC drivers is registers them.

Comment: Yeah, but its giving me a netezza exception while I'm trying to connect to oracle now.

Comment: What are the URLs you are using?

Comment: I don't know netezza, but it seems like it throws exceptions instead of skipping URLs it doesn't understand.

Comment: 1.  Class.forName() is unnecessary and has been for a decade or more.  It's ok to delete that now.
2.  What is the error you're getting?

Comment: The first one was - jdbc:netezza://(some ip):(some host)/(some name)

Comment: And the second one replace jdbc:netezza with jdbc:oracle:thin

Comment: The error is - org.netezza.util.PSQLEexception: Invalid URL format

Comment: see this for guidance on how to set up the oracle connection string:
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC

Comment: I can set up the oracle connection separately (when I don't do netezza). But the problem arises when I try to switch from netezza to Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally got the code to work. What I did was that I defined a new set of ResultSet and Connection variables (rstru2 and conn2). and used those for the Oracle connection.